# Spending partial amount of funds from a paper wallet created with moneroaddress.org and then deleting it from the cli wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Looking through the docs: https://getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#sweepdust

How does one import a monero private key and spend only a some of the coins from it and then deleting the private key?

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking. sweep_dust has nothing to do with spending and is almost obsolete. Are you looking for a way to make temporary wallet, scan&spend, and delete the wallet, all using RPC?

Comment: i dont want to delete the paper private key. i just want to spend from the paper private key and then delete it from the wallet itself. basically spend from cold storage, but not *sweep* it.